# Trick play thumbnail on exoplayer media3

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, android-media3

I'm working with an HLS playlist that provides `#EXT-X-IMAGE-STREAM-INF` tag containing thumbnails for every 10 seconds of video frames. Currently, I'm using ExoPlayer Media3 for video streaming on Android. I'm implementing a feature that allows users to view these thumbnails when they fast-forward or rewind during video playback.

I would like to know if there are any APIs or methods available within ExoPlayer Media3 that support this trick play thumbnail display functionality. If so, could you please provide guidance or code examples on how to implement this feature?

My HLS playlist provides the following data:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=820000,BANDWIDTH=1030000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=29.970,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8?thumbnails=548
#EXT-X-IMAGE-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=10000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="jpeg",URI="images-640x360/tpl-0-5480-548.m3u8?thumbnails=548"
```

images-640x360/tpl-0-5480-548.m3u8 provides the following data:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-IMAGES-ONLY
#EXTINF:10,
#EXT-X-TILES:RESOLUTION=640x360,LAYOUT=1x1,DURATION=10
seg-0-0.hls.jpg
#EXTINF:10,
#EXT-X-TILES:RESOLUTION=640x360,LAYOUT=1x1,DURATION=10
seg-0-10.hls.jpg
#EXTINF:10,
#EXT-X-TILES:RESOLUTION=640x360,LAYOUT=1x1,DURATION=10
seg-0-20.hls.jpg
#EXTINF:10,
#EXT-X-TILES:RESOLUTION=640x360,LAYOUT=1x1,DURATION=10
seg-0-30.hls.jpg
#EXTINF:10,
#EXT-X-TILES:RESOLUTION=640x360,LAYOUT=1x1,DURATION=10
seg-0-40.hls.jpg
#EXTINF:10,
#EXT-X-TILES:RESOLUTION=640x360,LAYOUT=1x1,DURATION=10
seg-0-50.hls.jpg
..
..
..
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Comment: Hey, sorry I can not help you with that. I am also working on Downloading HLS files on Android. I came across many different formatted HLS files, but none contained a thumbnail of every 10 seconds or so. Can you please mention the source of this HLS file? So I can also dive deep and fix this use case in my app. Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: @WaqasYounis It's a secured HLS URL that has tokenization and IP address validation. The HLS won't work if I share it here. It was generated from Flussonic, if this helps. https://flussonic.com/en-US/doc/jpeg-thumbnails/#on-demand-jpeg-thumbnail-generation